# Switching From Office 365 to Office 2019

Tags: microsoft-office

If I uninstall Office 365 and install Office 2019 will I lose all documents created with Office 2019? Had problems with the activation, 365 went dead today couldn't type or anything.

Comment: Your documents are not connected to the version of Office you are using.  You could uninstall office and your documents would continue to exist.  However, worth pointing out that an Office 2019 is expensive, and would require a license key in order to install it.  Since Office 365 build of Microsoft Word & Excel is a newer build than Office 2019 you you will have to uninstall Office 365.  I suggest the [Office Removal Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8) when you do that.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1**

Will you cancel Microsoft 365 apps subscription or will you just uninstall Microsoft 365 apps?

1. If you just uninstall Microsoft 365 apps, **this action won't let you lose files**. These fiels may not be opened normally until you intsall a new Office.
2. If you would cancel Microsoft 365 apps subscription, where are your files stored?

Are they on your local computer?

If yes, uninstalling or re-installing Office won't let you lose files.

If your files are stored on OneDrive cloud and exceed 5G, it is recommended to migrate files that exceed 5G to another place before canceling subscription.

As per Microsoft account has free 5G of OneDrive storage, but Microsoft 365 apps subscriptions generally have at least 1 TB of OneDrive storage.

**Question 2**

Is there any error messgae?

I suggest you go to Control Panel, find the Microsoft 365 apps and [perfrom a Online Repair](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b) .

If this action does not work, you may uinstall if first, and then [re-install it from your account](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/download-and-install-or-reinstall-microsoft-365-or-office-2019-on-a-pc-or-mac-4414eaaf-0478-48be-9c42-23adc4716658).